# Klocwork warning MISRA.STMT.COND.NOT_BOOLEAN with overriden ASSERT macro

Tags: c++, static-analysis, klocwork

I'm working on a large project and we use Klocwork to ensure some code quality.
The project uses some templated ASSERT (and some other SMART_ASSERT) macro, which I override when using Klocwork (as recommended here : https://developer.klocwork.com/documentation/en/insight/10-1/tuning-cc-analysis )
Klocwork now sees my 2 ASSERT macros as :

```
#define ASSERT(x) do { if (!(x)) abort(); } while (0)
#define SMART_ASSERT(sa_level,x,msg) do { if (!(x)) abort(); } while (0)
```

But still, lines like that :

```
SMART_ASSERT(sa_warning,true,"Msg on wrong interface:discarded");
SMART_ASSERT(sa_warning,m_FactoriesTables[msgType][msgId] != 0,"No Factory for Rx Msg");
SMART_ASSERT(sa_debug,(crError != 0),"CtlPath No ErrCr Available");
SMART_ASSERT(sa_debug,(m_pools[poolId] != 0),"Pool Not Created");
```

ends up with a `MISRA.STMT.COND.NOT_BOOLEAN` warning :

```
"Condition of if or loop statement has type '0' instead of 'boolean' "
```

Any idea on how to correct this warning ?

Thanks

SOKS

Comment: Surely it doesn't like your `while (0)` code.  Who does :)  Misra does not like a fast moving robot to get assertive.  You need to make sure that none of this survives when NDEBUG is #defined.  And that you tool looks at the code with it defined.

Comment: Fast and true answer ... I spent an hour looking at those if statement, without questioning the while statement ...
None is these macro redefinition survive in our Release configuration since it's a specific configuration. Thanks !